# heroku uninitialized constant user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I have a rails application using devise for authentication. It works when deployed locally but when push to Heroku I get this error

```
2014-07-03T14:20:17.235816+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Users (NameError)
```

Here is the file it is referring to

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    before_create :create_associated_records

    ROLES = [ROLE_STUDENT = 'student', ROLE_GRADUATE = 'graduate', 
         ROLE_INSTITUTIONAL_ADMIN = 'role_recruiter', ROLE_ADMIN = 'admin']

    def create
        @user = User.create(user_params)
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
    end

end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should either move

```
/app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb
```

to

```
/app/app/controllers/users/users_controller.rb
```

or change

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
```

to

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
```

This is due to the `::`, which denotes a location. `Users::SessionsController` would be looking for `./Users/SessionController`, which is a relative path to the current tree level (`controllers`).